# Sceen is unresponsive and refreshes constantly in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, xorg, dell

After I login, none of the icons are clickable, after sometime the cursor shifts to the lower-right corner and the screen refreshes. These sequence of events keeps repeating itself.

I reinstalled xorg and gnome-shell, but it did not help.
I have pasted below the contents of the syslog file.

```
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Killing process 4574 (gnome-shell) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: Failed to start GNOME Shell on X11.
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 13.
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Jul  3 22:03:28 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
Jul  3 22:04:58 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Killing process 4593 (gnome-shell) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Killing process 4597 (gdbus) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: Failed to start GNOME Shell on X11.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 14.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Jul  3 22:05:04 Inspiron-5559 systemd[1361]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

Comment: Have you tested whether the issue persists in other DE's?

Comment: Does DE mean device emulator?

Comment: No, Desktop Environment :)